# Replacing 0 values with the minimum value of the row in r

Tags: r, replace

I have data like this [original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8JcH.png)

I want to replace 0 values with the minimum value of each row (excluding 0), and I tried the following code

```
gapFill_data <- 
  data %>% 
  mutate_all(., ~ replace(., . == 0, min(as.numeric(.[.>0]))))
```

It doesn't work, and give me warnings like "In min(as.numeric(.[. > 0])) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf."
Below is the transformed data.
[transformed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4HXD.png)

I have tried to replace "min(as.numeric(.[.>0])))" with "5" in the code, then all 0 values were replaces with 5. So I guess the problem is here "min(as.numeric(.[.>0])))". Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post images of data, but instead use `head` or `dput` to show some example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mutate` is used to operate on data column-wise. If you want to do this rowwise one way in base R would be to use `apply` with margin as 1.

```
gapFill_data <- data

gapFill_data[] <- t(apply(data, 1, function(x) 
                          replace(x, x == 0, min(x[x > 0], na.rm = TRUE))))

gapFill_data

#  a b c d
#1 1 3 1 1
#2 2 2 3 2
#3 3 4 2 2
#4 4 2 1 1
#5 5 3 4 3
```

**data**

```
data <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = c(3, 0, 4, 2, 3), c = c(0, 3, 2, 1, 4), d = 0)
data
#  a b c d
#1 1 3 0 0
#2 2 0 3 0
#3 3 4 2 0
#4 4 2 1 0
#5 5 3 4 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does perfectly solve the problem. mutate works on column-wise data though, can we use rowwis() function to change it to row-wise?

Comment: `rowwise` usually works better if you want to add/edit only 1 column. If you want to stick with `tidyverse` I think a better option is to get data in long format perform the replacement and get it back in wide format.

Comment: well. understand, thanks again.